# Replace value with last value where flag was set to 1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where each row contains all the fields that changed during some event, and a flag associated with each field to flag if the field was updated. For simplicity I only show here the "status" field, but they are several other fields as well.
In cases where a given field was not modified by the event, the field is set to null and so is the flag.

```
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id |        date         | status | flag_changed_status |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-03 19:32:17 | TODO   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:46:07 | WIP    |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:53:53 |        |                     | //this line was generated because another field changed
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:56:53 |        |                     | //this line was generated because another field changed
|  1 | 2020-01-08 16:02:31 | Done   |                   1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

My goal is to replace the field values for the rows where the field was not changed with the last value it had when the flag was equal to one, e.g get :

```
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id |        date         | status | flag_changed_status |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-03 19:32:17 | TODO   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:46:07 | WIP    |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:53:53 | WIP    |                     |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:56:53 | WIP    |                     |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 16:02:31 | Done   |                   1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I understand that I want to use the `last_value` analytical function in Bigquery, and I tried :

```
SELECT ID_DEMANDE, date, status, 
last_value(status) OVER (ORDER BY flag_changed_status, DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as current_status, flag_changed_status 
FROM table ORDER BY  id, DATE
```

The idea was that by using the flag in the order by function, the rows where the flag was set to null would be put in first, and then the last_value(status) would be the last value where flag_changed_status was set to 1

But this can only work if I use ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING, because the `ORDER BY` clause will be processed before the window frame clause (rows between ...), thus for the rows where flag_changed_status is null, after the order by is processed, the current row number is 0, so the last value between unbounded preceding and current row is always null.

Is there any way to first run the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING and then the ORDER BY, so that last_value(status) will return the last value preceding the current row where the flag was set to one ? Or is there something much simpler, still using analytical functions to allow me to complete all the different fields in one query ?

Edit :
I really want to copy the status that was set the last time the flag was set, even if this status is null, that is why I am trying to use the flag in the order by. That is if the initial table is :

```
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id |        date         | status | flag_changed_status |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-03 19:32:17 | TODO   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:46:07 | null   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:53:53 | null   |                null |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:56:53 | null   |                null |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:57:53 | WIP    |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:58:53 | null   |                null |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 16:02:31 | Done   |                   1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I would need:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id |        date         | status | flag_changed_status |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-03 19:32:17 | TODO   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:46:07 | null   |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:53:53 | null   |                null | // we copy the last status where the flag was 1, and it is null
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:56:53 | null   |                null |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:57:53 | WIP    |                   1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-08 15:58:53 | WIP    |                null | //only this line changes
|  1 | 2020-01-08 16:02:31 | Done   |                   1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

But it seems to be too complicated, so I will just replace all the nulls where the flag is set to 1 with a custom status, and then a simple last_value(status IGNORE NULLS) as @gordon-linoff was suggesting will provide almost the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp),
  LAST_VALUE(status IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY date) AS updated_status
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    COUNTIF(flag_changed_status = 1) OVER(ORDER BY `date`) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row id  date                status  flag_changed_status updated_status   
1   1   2020-01-03 19:32:17 TODO    1                   TODO     
2   1   2020-01-08 15:46:07 null    1                   null     
3   1   2020-01-08 15:53:53 null    null                null     
4   1   2020-01-08 15:56:53 null    null                null     
5   1   2020-01-08 15:57:53 WIP     1                   WIP  
6   1   2020-01-08 15:58:53 null    null                WIP  
7   1   2020-01-08 16:02:31 Done    1                   Done
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `lag(ignore nulls)`.  But BigQuery doesn't support that.  Instead, use `first_value()`/`last_value()`:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, '2020-01-03 19:32:17' as date, 'TODO' as status, 1 as file_changed_status union all
      select 1 as id, '2020-01-08 15:46:07' as date, 'WIP ' as status, 1 as file_changed_status union all
      select 1 as id, '2020-01-08 15:53:53' as date, null as status, null  as file_changed_status union all
      select 1 as id, '2020-01-08 15:56:53' as date, null as status,  null as file_changed_status union all
      select 1 as id, '2020-01-08 16:02:31' as date, 'Done' as status, 1 as file_changed_status
     )
select t.*,
       last_value(status ignore nulls) over (order by date) as imputed_status
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't think that using first_value will work, as it will just get the first status over the partition - here `TODO` instead of the last status where the flag was set to 1 - here `WIP` - which is my goal here. 
Moreover, the reason why I need to use the flag is that I want to imput the current status based on the status the last time that the flag was set, even if that status value is null, in which case I want to leave all following rows to null until we have a new value where the flag is set to 1

Comment: @L.Morin . . . I should have used `last_value()` instead.  This works.  I've used it in a lot of code.  I added sample data and it returns the data you want.

Comment: `last_value()` is indeed what I need to use, but it didn't solve the issue of copying the last value where the flag was set, as I could not necessarily ignore nulls, as explained in the edit part of my post. But I will just replace all the nulls where the flag is set to 1 with a custom status, and then your answer would work, so I will accept it thanks

Comment: @L.Morin . . . The flag didn't seem important for the data and question.  You can use a `case when` to convert the value to `NULL` when the flag is not `1`.